# How to calculate $P(A|B1,B2,B3)$? (it is not a duplicate)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have 4 variables and I know the following probabilities:

1) $P(A|B_1)$; $P(A|B_2)$; $P(A|B_3)$;

2) $P(B_1)$; $P(B_2)$; $P(B_3)$.

3) $P(A)$

Of course, I have:

4) $P(A,B_1)$; $P(A,B_2)$; $P(A,B_3)$;

And I need:

$P(A|B_1,B_2,B_3)$

Is it possible calculate this probability using some rule o theorem of probability?

I was thinking to use Chain's rule but for this case, It is enough data.

What I have is a table like following:

[image: Table]

It contains the nationality for the name "Bernhard" of people who live in Spain. The name represents the variable $B_1$. Same for $B_2$ and $B_3$ (surname 1 and surname 2).

What I need is given name, surname 1 and surname 2 ($B_1$, $B_2$ and $B_3$) what is the probability of being from Germany (for example).

Comment: The known information is not enough.

Comment: I don't think you have enough information. You need to know how much the events $B_1$, $B_2$, and $B_3$ overlap

Comment: Edited. @stochastic, overlap? what means? Be free to assume they are independent or something you need. Thanks

Comment: You can probably bound it, by first assuming independence of the names, and then assuming maximal dependence.

Comment: @MikeY suppose they are indenpendent, how will you proceed?

Comment: Help me please :-(

Comment: By $P(A|B_1,B_2,B_3)$ do you mean $P(A|B_1\, or\, B_2\, or\, B_3)$? Given what I understand from your explanations, the answer you are looking for is $\sum P(A|B_i)/\sum P(B_i)$. But this is not exactly the answer to the first part of the question

Comment: Dear @stochastic, no. I mean $B_1, B_2, B_3 = B_1 \cap B_2 \cap B_3$.

Comment: What am I misunderstanding here: If each $B_i$ is a different name, how would you have an intersection for $B_i$s? Is $B_1\cap B_2$ all the people who have the name $B_1$ and also have the name $B_2$, or people who have either the name $B_1$ or $B_2$?

Comment: Because  rember that $ P(B_1 | B_2) = \frac{P(B_1 \cap B_2)}{P(B_2)}$ and I have  $P(B_1 | B_2)$ and $P(B_2)$.

Comment: I found something related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29510/proper-way-to-combine-conditional-probability-distributions-of-the-same-random-v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two extremes of dependency here. If the $B$ terms are both independent so $P(B_1,B_2)=P(B_1)P(B_2)$ and conditionally independent on $A$ so $P(B_1,B_2|A)=P(B_1|A)P(B_2|A)$ then

$$
P(A|B_1,B_2,B_3)=\frac{P(B_1,B_2,B_3|A)P(A)}{P(B_1,B_2,B_3)}
$$
$$
=\frac{P(B_1|A)P(B_2|A)P(B_3|A)}{P(B_1)P(B_2)P(B_3)}P(A)
$$
$$
=\frac{P(A|B_1)P(B_1)P(A|B_2)P(B_2)P(A|B_3)P(B_3)}{P(A)P(A)P(A)P(B_1)P(B_2)P(B_3)}P(A)
$$
$$
=\frac{P(A|B_1)P(A|B_2)P(A|B_3)}{P(A)^2}
$$
Similarly, if the terms are completely dependent and conditionally dependent
$$
P(A|B_1,B_2,B_3)=\frac{P(B_1,B_2,B_3|A)P(A)}{P(B_1,B_2,B_3)}
$$
$$
=\frac{P(B_1|A)}{P(B_1)}P(A)
$$
$$
=P(A|B_1)
$$
These should form (loose? tight?) bounds.

Comment: You are amazing man!!!! Thanks a lot!! Awesome!!!! Very good answer.